# Ubntu desktop VS core

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am beginner in this ROS and studying to integrate melodic with our target device, might be arm64.
Have one silly question, as far as I know, we can integrate ROS on Ubuntu or as well othres.
However, I am confused that does it mean we can use both Ubuntu desktop and Core version also ?
Since I thought we have to use Ubuntu core for embedded device.
Sincerely,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321556/ubntu-desktop-vs-core/) by [hungrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/40975/hungrok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
you can use ros on ubuntu-desktop or ubuntu-server or armhf or arm64 ...(pls see this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation)) and ros tested on embedded system like odroid , jetson , upboard , rasbery pi  , ...

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hungrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/40975/hungrok/) on 2019-04-22**:
Thanks your information. Would you answer my understanding is right that we have to use only desktop or server not core version. Sincerey,

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2019-04-22**:
you can use ubuntu core version with  Snapcraft and also pls see this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882010/ros-on-ubuntu-core-issues)

**Comment by [hungrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/40975/hungrok/) on 2019-04-23**:
Again thanks your comment.
So, we can use both ubuntu desktop or core depending upon our choice.
I would like to have another question with new ask.
Thanks.